# How do I change versions of Node and yarn mentioned in package.json with Volta?

Tags: volta

I have a project cloned to my local machine from GitHub which has

```json
  "volta": {
    "node": "14.17.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.10"
  },
```

in its `package.json` file.

When I type `node --version`, terminal outputs `v18.7.0`.

How do I make `volta` change versions of `node` and `yarn` to the mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volta automatically uses the correct yarn/node version if you `cd` into your folder. However, any yarn/node command will trigger Volta to install and use the pinned version if not installed.